# Key confusion in python

Tags: python, regex

Hey friends i have seen some weird code.Am new to python programming.The code is

```
import re, collections

mylist = ['Probes', 'Gene.symbol', 'Gene.Title', 'GO1', 'GO2', 'GO3', 'ADX_KD_06.ip', 'ADX_KD_24.ip', 'ADX_LG_06.ip', 'ADX_LG_24.ip', 'ADX_LV_06.ip', 'ADX_LV_24.ip', 'ADX_SP_06.ip', 'ADX_SP_24.ip', 'ADX_LN_06.id', 'ALM_LN_06.id', 'ALM_LV_06.ip', 'ALM_SP_06.ip', 'K3SPG_LV_06.ip', 'K3SPG_SP_06.ip', 'KKK_LN_06.id', 'KKK_LV_06.ip', 'KKK_SP_06.ip', 'ENDCN_LV_06.in', 'ENDCN_SP_06.in', 'bCD_LV_06.ip', 'bCD_SP_06.ip', 'ADX_LV_06.id', 'ADX_SP_06.id', 'ALM_LV_06.id', 'ALM_SP_06.id', 'D35_LN_06.id', 'K3SPG_LN_06.id', 'K3_LV_06.id', 'K3_SP_06.id', 'bCD_LN_06.id', 'D35_LV_06.id', 'D35_SP_06.id', 'K3SPG_LV_06.id', 'K3SPG_SP_06.id', 'bCD_LV_06.id', 'bCD_SP_06.id', 'ENDCN_KD_06.in', 'ENDCN_LG_06.in', 'Probes', 'Gene.symbol', 'ADX_KD_06.ip', 'ADX_KD_24.ip', 'ADX_LG_06.ip', 'ADX_LG_24.ip', 'ADX_LV_06.ip', 'ADX_LV_24.ip', 'ADX_SP_06.ip', 'ADX_SP_24.ip', 'ADX_LN_06.id', 'ALM_LN_06.id', 'ALM_LV_06.ip', 'ALM_SP_06.ip', 'K3SPG_LV_06.ip', 'K3SPG_SP_06.ip', 'KKK_LN_06.id', 'KKK_LV_06.ip', 'KKK_SP_06.ip', 'ENDCN_LV_06.in', 'ENDCN_SP_06.in', 'bCD_LV_06.ip', 'bCD_SP_06.ip', 'ADX_LV_06.id', 'ADX_SP_06.id', 'ALM_LV_06.id', 'ALM_SP_06.id', 'D35_LN_06.id', 'K3SPG_LN_06.id', 'K3_LV_06.id', 'K3_SP_06.id', 'bCD_LN_06.id', 'D35_LV_06.id', 'D35_SP_06.id', 'K3SPG_LV_06.id', 'K3SPG_SP_06.id', 'bCD_LV_06.id', 'bCD_SP_06.id', 'ENDCN_KD_06.in', 'ENDCN_LG_06.in']

regex = re.compile(r'([\w\d]+)_(\w\w)_(\d\d)\.(\w\w)')

first_part_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)

second_part_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
```

## second instance of 'Probes', to separate the first and second parts

```
cutoff_index = mylist.index('Probes', 1) 

for i, string in enumerate(mylist):

matched = regex.match(string)

if not matched:

    continue

rg1, rg2, rg3, rg4 = matched.groups()

key = rg1 + rg3

if i < cutoff_index:

    first_part_dict[key].append(i)

else:

    second_part_dict[key].append(i)
```

We can see the list above to be separated into two parts, delimited by 'Probes', 'Gene.symbol', 'Gene.Title', 'GO1', 'GO2', 'GO3' and 'Probes', 'Gene.symbol'.

The regex for the components of the first and second part is:

```
([\w\d]+)_(\w\w)_(\d\d)\.(\w\w)
  rg1      rg2     rg3    rg4
```

Which should match string like this `ADX_SP_06.ip` or `K3SPG_LN_06.id`

My question is that ..I didnt understood the use of `first_part_dict[key].append(i)`
 in the code.I know i is given as the index here.Am not so good in regex and i think the matched portion is the number.So the key will act as a number and first_part_dict  is a dictionary.Is the value of the index i is stored to the dictionary first_part_dict ??..

Am really confused..Please help me in undersding this..Any help would be appreciated ..And sorry for this long question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dictionary being used is a dictionary with a text/string key and a list as value.

What `first_part_dict[key].append(i)` is doing is it is appending (or adding) the value of `i` to the list corresponding to the key `key` of the dictionary `first_part_dict`.

If the key was `ADX06`, then the dictionary will go from `{'ADX06': []}` to `{'ADX06': [1]}` should the value of `i` be 1.

---

I'll put a walkthrough just to illustrate:

```
mylist = ['Probes', 'Gene.symbol', 'Gene.Title', 'GO1', 'GO2', 'GO3', 'ADX_KD_06.ip', 'ADX_KD_24.ip', 'ADX_LG_06.ip'
for i, string in enumerate(mylist):
matched = regex.match(string)
if not matched:
    continue
rg1, rg2, rg3, rg4 = matched.groups()
key = rg1 + rg3
if i < cutoff_index:
    first_part_dict[key].append(i)
else:
    second_part_dict[key].append(i)
```

When you pass through the loop the first time, you get `i = 0` and `string = 'Probes'`. Since `Probes` doesn't match the regex, the loop skips to the next item through `continue`.

This time, you get `i = 1` and `string = 'Gene.symbol`. Once again, the string doesn't match the regex, so you skip to the next item. This goes on until you get the 7th item: `ADX_KD_06.ip`. Here, you have `i = 6` and `string = 'ADX_KD_06.ip'` which matches the regex.

From that, you get `rg1 = ADX`, `rg2 = LG`, `rg3 = 06` and `rg4 = ip`. The key thus becomes `ADX06` and you get `first_part_dict[key].append(i)` executing.

This will create the key `ADX06` in the dictionary `first_part_dict` and append `6` to its value list. Right now, you have the dict having `{'ADX06': [6]}`. The loop then continues on the next item.

This time, we have `i = 7` and `string = 'ADX_KD_24.ip'`. This matches the regex and couple of lines later, you have `first_part_dict[key].append(i)` executing.

This will create the key `ADX24` in the dictionary `first_part_dict` and append `7` to its value list. Right now, you have the dict having `{'ADX06': [6], 'ADX24': [7]}`. The loop then continues on the next item.

This time, we have `i = 8` and `string = 'ADX_LG_06.ip'`. This matches the regex and couple of lines later, you have `first_part_dict[key].append(i)` executing again.

This will create the key `ADX06` in the dictionary... but wait! That key already exists, so it will instead append `8` to its existing value list. Right now, you have the dict having `{'ADX06': [6, 8], 'ADX24': [7]}`.

This goes on and on until all the items in the list has been treated.

Comment: why the value of i is 1 there ?

Comment: @user3501595 That was an example. `i` could be 2 and if it were 2, then you'd have `{'ADX06': [2]}`. The code is using `for i, string in enumerate(mylist):` which means that the value if `i` will go from `0` to the number of elements-1 in the list `mylist`.

Comment: @user3501595 I added a small walkthrough through the loop for the first few items in the list. Maybe that will help you understand better?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to focus on

> My question is that ..I didnt understood the use of first_part_dict[key].append(i)
>   in the code.I know i is given as the index here.Am not so good in regex and i think the matched portion is the number.So the key will act as a number and first_part_dict is a dictionary.Is the value of the index i is stored to the dictionary first_part_dict ??..

It seems based on some condition first_part_dict or second_part_dict will be populated.
E.g. {'ADX06': []} , next iteration --> {'ADX06': [1,]} . A lil while later --> {'ADX06': [1,4,]}

P.S> I hope you are initializing first_part_dict[key] with [] for all potential keys, or just add first_part_dict[key] = [] as you go.

Comment: i just need to know what will be the variable  key is ? Is key a number ?

Comment: How the value 4 comes in {'ADX06': [1,4,]}..Can you explain more ?

Comment: Key wont be number with ([\w\d]+) meant for rg1 which is used to form key.

Comment: A lil while later --> {'ADX06': [1,4,]} will not be there. Sorry for that. That was just an example to show iterable.

Comment: according to jerry he says it would come like {'ADX06': [1]} and you says {'ADX06': [1,4,]}.what is right really ?